# Enumerating and displaying files in the current directory and selecting by number to search for the file via cmd line

Tags: python

I'm developing a command line tool that searches for certain string (hex, ascii, PAN etc...) data in log files. I have a few lines written that uses a regular expression to filter the search. Ideally, I want to be able to visually see all .txt and .log files in the current directory, have them enumerated, so I can choose a number to select a file to search through for a particular string (filtered by re). Any help is appreciated. Here's what I have so far:

```
logfile = open("file.txt", "r")
regex = re.compile(r'3[1-9]\d{10}') #re search for a 12 digit string that starts with 3, 
#and whos second number is 0-9.

for line in logfile:
    search_string = regex.findall(line)
    for word in search_string:
        print word
```

Comment: Why re-do this in python and not use grep?

Comment: It seems you show little code while asking for help in many different unrelated fields, in a way that's a bit confusing, at least to me. The answer I would think of given just the title of your question (ignoring the rest) is: `import sys f=sys.argv[1] logfile=open(f, 'r')`. This way if you work in a unix or windows shell/cmd you do (suppose it's windows): `C:\Documents and settings\User706808>myscript.py myfile.log`. You can get more help if you explain clearly what you need, one thing at a time.

Comment: @qor72 I need to use this on windows based PC and embedded linux/unix based hardware.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't answer the entire question, but if you're looking to do some sort of interactive shell based operations, the [cmd](http://docs.python.org/library/cmd.html) module from the standard library is a good starting point.